# UISpec4J: Returning a Trigger from a Combobox selection?

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, uispec4j

This question is for the [UISpec4J](http://www.uispec4j.org) testing framework, for testing Java GUIs...

I'm trying to test an error message pop-up window (modal) that results from making a selection from a ComboBox, but I'm not sure how to return a Trigger object from the select action.

Here's a snippet:

```
WindowInterceptor
    .init(window.getComboBox("ComboBoxName").select("Choice that will cause error message"))    // Problem here
    .process(new WindowHandler() {
        public Trigger process(Window errorMessage) {
            // Do stuff...
        }
    })
    .run();
```

In the `.init()` line, I'm supposed to return a Trigger object (like `button.triggerClick()`), but I don't know how to do that from a ComboBox selection.

Can someone please tell me how to return a trigger from a ComboBox selection?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you do something like:

```
 WindowInterceptor
    .init(new Trigger() {
        public void run() throws Exception {
            window.getComboBox("ComboBoxName").select("Choice that will cause erromessage");
        })
    .run();
```

It looks messy but it is an option to extract to make it read nicer. Please note this is untested, it's just what I would expect to do.

Comment: Yup, that did it.
Thanks so much!